# find file path from multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, find, filepath, multidimensional-array

I got directory array below.

I will make a file search in this array. For example path.php , survey.php...
If file is found , how should a construct the path.

for path.php

I want function to return  '/survey/config/path.php'

```
Array
(
[survey] => Array
    (
        [config] => Array
            (
                [0] => path.php
                [1] => routes.php
            )

        [controllers] => Array
            (
                [0] => admin.php
                [1] => giris.php
            )

        [models] => Array
            (
                [0] => giris.php
            )

        [views] => Array
            (
                [0] => admin_form.php
                [1] => widget.php
                [2] => yeni_form.php
            )

        [widgets] => Array
            (
                [0] => survey.php
            )

    )
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function find_file_path($dir_structure, $filename) {
    foreach($dir_structure as $dir => $subpath) {
        if(is_array($subpath)) {
            $sub_found = find_file_path($subpath, $filename);
            if($sub_found) {
                return "/" . $dir . $sub_found;
            }
        } else {
            if($subpath === $filename) {
                return "/$filename";
            }
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it returns survey/config/0/path.php. How can i remove "0" or "1" ? just survey/config/path.php

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, you should click the green checkmark outline next to it to mark it as "Accepted". :)